# angular 4 route link activ for parent

Tags: angular4-router

```
<li class="category-container main-menu-link">
        <div class="category">
          <i class="category-icon fa fa-film"></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="genre-list">
          <a [routerLink]="['bygenre', genre]" *ngFor="let genre of genres">
            <li>{{genre}}</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

How to apply an active link to a very distant parent link
I want to apply it to

```
<li class="category-container main-menu-link">
```

Answer (score 1):

**problem solved**

```
<li class="category-container main-menu-link" [style.color]="rla.isActive ? '#1696FF': 'white'"  >
        <div class="category">
          <i class="category-icon fa fa-film"></i>
        </div>
        <ul class="genre-list" [routerLinkActive]="" #rla="routerLinkActive">
          <a [routerLink]="['bygenre', genre]"
             *ngFor="let genre of genres">
            <li>{{genre}}</li>
          </a>
        </ul>
      </li>
```